# Ajax в WordPress. Как отключить переход на отдельные страницы или другие варианты

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины, ajax-load

Использую плагин DZS Ajaxer Lite, все работает отлично, но есть одно "но". Когда добавляю в корзину товар из категории, он подгружает УРЛ вида `/?add-to-cart=ид-продукта`. Если отключаю плагин, то товар отлично добавляется и урл не меняется.
WooCommerce AJAX Cart тоже работает параллельно.

Вот и вопрос: можно ли сказать плагину не учитывать урл, если он начинается с `?add-to-cart`. Или есть другие варианты решения?

Comment: https://free.online-media.biz/product-category/tartaletki/
Вот сайт

Comment: Весьма вряд ли плагин имеет такую настройку. Надо как-то блокировать это своим кодом на js.